# issue with Zen desk Api name User: Name: is too short (minimum one character)

Tags: java, rest, zendesk

When i tried to hit the zen desk api called user with a json request,it hits API successfully but getting an error **Name: is too short (minimum one character)**

I logged the request,and tested this request with a POSTER tool that time i was successfull in my attempt account got created in zend side

but when i tried the same with java code getting the above error,So help me in this issue

The logged request is

```
{
"user":
{
"name":"TEST CASE2",
"email":"case22@gmail.com",
"external_id":"5335356",
"role":"end-user",
"verified":"true"
}
}
```

And my code is

```
    public static void createUser(String name, String email, String spAccountId,String verified) {
                HttpClient c = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String serviceUrl = "https://domain/api/v2/users.json";
                HttpPost p = new HttpPost(serviceUrl);
                p.setHeader("ContentType", "application/json");          
                p.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                p.setHeader("Authorization","Basic tyytytreytytytreytytre=");               
                JsonObject jsonObjectRepresentation = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("user", Json.createObjectBuilder()
                        .add("name", name)
                        .add("email", email)
                        .add("external_id", spAccountId)
                        .add("role", "end-user")        
                        .add("verified", verified).build()).build();
                System.out.println(jsonObjectRepresentation.toString());
                p.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonObjectRepresentation.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                HttpResponse r = c.execute(p);
                JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new InputStreamReader(r.getEntity().getContent()));
                JsonObject jsonObject = reader.readObject();
                reader.close();         
                System.out.println("jsonObject@@@@@@@"+jsonObject); 
    }
```

out put from my java code

```
{"error":"RecordInvalid","description":"Record validation errors","details":{"name":[{"description":"Name: is too short (minimum one character)"}]}}
```

Out put From Poster tool:

```
{"user":{"id":502206130,"url":"https://domain.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/502206130.json","name":"TEST CASE3","email":"case3@me.com","created_at":"2014-07-17T08:12:04Z","updated_at":"2014-07-17T08:12:05Z","time_zone":"Hawaii","phone":null,"photo":null,"locale_id":16,"locale":"fr","organization_id":null,"role":"end-user","verified":true,"external_id":"434355","tags":[],"alias":null,"active":true,"shared":false,"shared_agent":false,"last_login_at":null,"signature":null,"details":null,"notes":null,"custom_role_id":null,"moderator":false,"ticket_restriction":"requested","only_private_comments":false,"restricted_agent":true,"suspended":false,"user_fields":{"abonnement_internet":null,"betapass":null,"box":null,"commune":null,"dcodeur_tns_tnt":null,"mac":null,"position_du_routeur":null,"routeur":null,"serial":null,"subscription":null}}}
```

Comment: i resolved my issue by using AsyncHttpClient

Answer (score 2):

I also had same problem, Solved using in header

> "Content-Type" : "application/json"

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I will suggest you one more way. Please use AsyncHttpClient instead of HttpClient

so I will format your code:

```
AsyncHttpClient client=new AsyncHttpClient();
JsonObject jsonObjectRepresentation = Json.createObjectBuilder()
    .add("user", Json.createObjectBuilder()
        .add("name", name)
        .add("email", email)
        .add("external_id", spAccountId)
        .add("role", "end-user")        
        .add("verified", verified).build()).build();    
Request request = client
    .preparePost("https://niutv.zendesk.com/api/v2/users.json")
    .setHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
    .setHeader("Content-Length", "" + jsonObjectRepresentation.toString()
        .length())
    .setHeader("Authorization", "Basic b2pAbml1LXR2LmNvbTpnMGFRNzVDUnhzQ0ZleFQ=")
    .setBody(jsonObjectRepresentation.toString()).build();
ListenableFuture<Response> r = null;
//ListenableFuture<Integer> f = null;
try {
    r = client.executeRequest(request);
    System.out.println(r.get().getResponseBody());
} catch(IOException e) {

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I've re-indented the code block so that it's a bit easier on the eyes. I've also made the code style a little more consistent with itself (which I know was inherited from @fresher's code, so it's not a criticism). Lastly, I added a few more newlines in so that there's no longer need to scroll horizontally to see everything.